# Memory issue in application in android

Tags: android

I am getting a large or big value from the webservice. I am using sax parser to parse the value and add it to an arraylist. From the arraylist I am adding to tablelayout with scrollview at the I am getting an out of memory error in android. Can anybody tell me what I need to do to solve the issue? Is there any way to increase the heap size or free heap memory? Can anybody tell me which parser is the best for parsing large xml files?

I have nearly 7000 to 10000 record like article details title

Any help would be appreciated

my stack trace :

```
II/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 16.810MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 4148 objects / 272832 bytes in 386ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 8704-byte alloc
ation
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 16.810MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 353ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Out of memory on a 8704-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(  992): "main" prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001b268 self=0
xbd00
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | sysTid=992 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-13440013
84
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:~1918)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1879)

I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1756)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:418)

I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1713)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:400)

I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1693)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:391)

I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.inquest.HomeSearchArticle$HomeSearchTask.onPostExecu
te(HomeSearchArticle.java:199)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.inquest.HomeSearchArticle$HomeSearchTask.onPostExecu
te(HomeSearchArticle.java:1)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(Async
Task.java:429)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363
)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.r
un(ZygoteInit.java:860)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:
618)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  992):
I/System.out(  992): ######out of memory error is###java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.270MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 8418 objects / 744936 bytes in 468ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.471MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 8605 objects / 481136 bytes in 428ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.583MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 5050 objects / 297248 bytes in 413ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.595MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 1927 objects / 77160 bytes in 515ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 1028-byte alloc
ation
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.594MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 79 objects / 1264 bytes in 495ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Out of memory on a 1028-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(  992): "main" prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001b268 self=0
xbd00
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | sysTid=992 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-13440013
84
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:~13
8)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:97)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:54)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:45)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:4914
)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:5176)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TableRow.getColumnsWidths(TableRow.java:3
08)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TableLayout.findLargestCells(TableLayout.
java:497)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TableLayout.measureVertical(TableLayout.j
ava:462)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.TableLayout.onMeasure(TableLayout.java:42
8)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(Scroll
View.java:893)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:276)

I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(Rel
ativeLayout.java:569)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.j
ava:361)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(Rel
ativeLayout.java:569)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.j
ava:361)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(Lin
earLayout.java:888)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayo
ut.java:619)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:
280)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup
.java:3023)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:24
5)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:76
3)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363
)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.r
un(ZygoteInit.java:860)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:
618)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  992):
D/AndroidRuntime(  992): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(  992): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
001b188)
E/AndroidRuntime(  992): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught e
xception
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.609MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 289 objects / 10728 bytes in 407ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 938-byte alloca
tion
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.609MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 402ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Out of memory on a 938-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(  992): "main" prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001b268 self=0
xbd00
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | sysTid=992 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-13440013
84
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractSt
ringBuilder.java:~97)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBu
ilder.java:131)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:273)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:138)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.doWrite(PrintWriter.java:711)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:686)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:661)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:729)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:492)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:623)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:316)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:234)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.crash(RuntimeInit.ja
va:315)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.unca
ughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java
:887)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java
:884)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  992):
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.614MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 64 objects / 5424 bytes in 447ms
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 754-byte alloca
tion
I/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Clamp target GC heap from 17.614MB to 16.000MB
D/dalvikvm(  992): GC freed 0 objects / 0 bytes in 440ms
E/dalvikvm-heap(  992): Out of memory on a 754-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm(  992): "main" prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001b268 self=0
xbd00
I/dalvikvm(  992):   | sysTid=992 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-13440013
84
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractSt
ringBuilder.java:~97)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBu
ilder.java:131)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:273)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:138)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.doWrite(PrintWriter.java:711)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:686)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:661)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:729)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:492)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:623)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:316)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at android.util.Log.getStackTraceString(Log.java:234)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.crash(RuntimeInit.ja
va:323)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.unca
ughtException(RuntimeInit.java:76)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java
:887)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java
:884)
I/dalvikvm(  992):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm(  992):
I/Process (   60): Sending signal. PID: 992 SIG: 3
I/dalvikvm(  992): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
I/dalvikvm(  992): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
D/dalvikvm(   60): GC freed 13970 objects / 689880 bytes in 201ms
```

Thanks

Comment: could you publish the stack trace? How big is the file? Are you closing the stream and setting it to null? Also you can look at the DDMS heap allocations to see where the memory is being allocated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar problem, although for a different application. Please see my post:
[Problem with downloading multiple files using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079335/problem-with-downloading-multiple-files-using-asynctask)