# How to get back the task completion status in AsyncTask

Tags: android, synchronization, android-asynctask

This is related to my previous post [Problem with downloading multiple files using AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079335/problem-with-downloading-multiple-files-using-asynctask)

I'm trying to download two video files and also show a ProgressDialog during the process. For this I'm using AsyncTask. I want the 1st download to complete, free up memory then start the 2nd download. I wrote the following code to achieve this, but it seems the 2nd download never begins.

```
startDownload() {
   DownloadFileAsync d1 = new DownloadFileAsync();
   d1.execute(videoPath+fileNames[0],fileNames[0]);

   if(d1.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
     d1 = null;
     DownloadFileAsync d2 = new DownloadFileAsync();
     d2.execute(videoPath+fileNames[1],fileNames[1]);
   }
}
```

Is there a way that I can get back the completion status of my 1st task & then start the 2nd ?

The following is the code of my DownloadFileAsync class:

```
class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lenghtOfFile);

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/videos/" + aurl[1]);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);                    
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();                
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;

    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC",progress[0]);
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        tv.append("\n\nFile Download Completed!");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As DKIT Android suggested, you could start the second download from onPostExecute, but only if for example download2 is null

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) 
{

   if (d2 == null)
   {
       d2 = new DownloadFileAsync();
       d2.execute(videoPath+fileNames[1],fileNames[1]);    
   }    
}
```

If you need to start more downloads, just write the method outside of your asynctask, which will check which download should be started next.

Answer (score 1):

Start your second download from within your first onPostExecute-method.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        tv.append("\n\nFile Download Completed!");
        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));            

        // Here you start your new AsyncTask...
    }
```

This code:

```
if(d1.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
 d1 = null;
 DownloadFileAsync d2 = new DownloadFileAsync();
 d2.execute(videoPath+fileNames[1],fileNames[1]);
```

}

...will execute once, and immediately after the first AsyncTask is executed, thus it will always be false. If you want to go that route, you need to do it in a while loop - which kind of defeats the point of making the task Async in the first place.

Comment: But in the real application I've to download several files not just 2. So, is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: I tried putting a while loop there while(d1.getStatus()==AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {...} but the entire application stalled. So, I was wondering if there is any better way to do it.

Comment: I kept the code for the 2nd download inside onPostExecute() method. But the 2nd task kept on executing for an infinite number of times. Please show me how to implement this logic for 5 continuous tasks (downloads)

Comment: you may write the for loop to initiate the dowdload Task instance and start the batch download
 if u want the 1st download to complete, free up memory then start the 2nd download.