# How do I download Image from Server If URL stored in ArrayList using Asynctask?

Tags: android, image, arraylist, android-asynctask

Images in a server and I have to download an image from the server. Image Url Stored in ArrayList using Asynctask.

how to download an image from `ArrayList URL`? I using `Download manager`  and custom download but its give not an actual response.

Comment: see this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/13983621/9408181

Answer (score 0):

you can use Picasso library.

```
for (String url : urlList) {
Picasso.with(this)
.load(url)
.into(new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded (final Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from){
        /* Save the bitmap or do something with it here */

        //Set it in the ImageView
        theView.setImageBitmap(bitmap); 
    }
});
}
```